# JMeter : Using the JSON Postprocessor _ALL variable in one more postprocessor to fetch the data

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jsr223, post-processor

I'm having a JSON data, from which I'm able to fetch some data from JSON Extractor post-processor.
And the data looks something like this,

```
group_1 = ["Scooter"]
group_2 = ["Bus","Jeep","Car"]
group_ALL = ["Scooter"],["Bus","Jeep","Car"]
group_matchNr = 2
```

So I want to fetch all this data (or accumulate) in only one array variable,

Example : `groups=["Scooter","Bus","Jeep","Car"]`

so that I loop it through all the individual data in the api calls in  a foreach loop.

example api call in foreach loop: [https://vehicles.com/${groups}](https://vehicles.com/$%7Bgroups%7D)

**My question is, I'm trying to write the groovy script to get all the data in groups variable. But unable to. I need your help in this and to configure the foreach controller also.**

Groovy Script I tried in JSR223 Postprocessor which did not work:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;
 
groups= vars.get("group_ALL"); 
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper(); 
jsonData = JSON.stringify(vars.get("groups"))  
String tempRemoveBr = jsonData.replaceAll("[",""); 
String tempRemoveBr1 = tempRemoveBr.replaceAll("]",""); 
String[] arrVehicles = tempRemoveBr1.split(",") 
for (int i=0;i<arrVehicles.size();i++) 
{
   log.info("arrVehicles[i]") 
} 
vars.put("arrVehicles",arrVehicles)
```

foreach controller configured as :

```
Input variable : arrVehicles 
start index : 0 
output variable name : vehicleN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you could achieve it using [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor), however I cannot come up with a proper configuration without seeing your full response.

If you want to process existing variables here is a Groovy script you could use:

```
def group1 = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(vars.get('group_1'))
def group2 = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(vars.get('group_2'))

def arrVehicles = group1 + group2

vars.put('arrVehicles', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(arrVehicles).toString())
```

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and Producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: This would work in case of 2 groups, thank you. But in case if there are multiple groups and the number of groups change every-time, what would be the code?
Tried this which did not work, please let me know the modification in this


`def arrVehicles1=null;
def group_matchNr1=new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(vars.get('group_matchNr'))
for(int i=0;i<(int)group_matchNr1;i++)
{
 group = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(vars.getObject('group_'+i))
 if(arrVehicles == null)
 {
  arrVehicles = group
 }
 else
 {
  arrVehicles = arrVehicles + group
 }
}`